# Loading of a flash swf not working (aborted) on IE or Firefox until you refresh many times

Tags: flash, iis, jwplayer

In IE / firefox the following embed:

```
<embed src="http://video.dmu.ac.uk/player51.swf" width="320"  height="260"  allowscriptaccess="always"  allowfullscreen="true"  flashvars="height=260&width=320&file=13610046_hi.mp4&streamer=rtmp://flash.dmu.ac.uk/media2/mp4:&searchbar=false&autostart=false&image=http://video.dmu.ac.uk/thumbnails/13610046.jpg"  />
```

served here:

http://www.streaming.co.uk/lee/legacy.htm

On IE (e.g. 9) it fails to load (flash appears not to start) most times until you hit refresh many times.

After doing this a straight reference in the url "http://video.dmu.ac.uk/player51.swf" fails to load with (aborted) shown in the result column of developer tools - network.

Firefox shows 'aborted' in debug-net directly on the embed html retrieval.

However once the embed does refresh right the straight url seems OK.

Another server is OK. Which points to the IIS on the problem server?

Any clues anyone?

Comment: I looks like your server must not be configured correctly for SWF files, perhaps?

If I go to this URL directly - http://video.dmu.ac.uk/player51.swf

I get this error:

The connection was reset
        
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Comment: thanks Ethan. I get that too. There is definately something up with this server and I think we are going to go for a completely new machine and setup from scratch.

Comment: Np. Okay, that sounds like a plan.